# Getting TS to complain about null comparison to a non-nullable field?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to get TS to complain about this?  I have `strictNullChecks` on

```
const foo: string = 'asdf';

if (foo !== null) {
    console.log(foo);
}
```

If, for instance, I change that condition to:

```
if (foo !== 42) {
```

I get:

> This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'string' and 'number' have no overlap.

Comment: You can use TSLint with [`strict-type-predicates`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/strict-type-predicates/)

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak --  `TSLint` isn't an option for us, unfortunately :(  But I'm afraid that might be the only answer

Comment: if you're using `ESLint` you could probably recreate the same effect with [`typescript-eslint`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) but you'd have to write the rule yourself. I would love to know why this exception exists if anyone has that info, it seems like it must be an intentional design choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cause an error with `===` because TS has special carve-outs that make comparison with `null`/`undefined` always allowed.

If you're willing to use a helper function, you can use a conditional type to ensure that `null` is a possible value of the tested expression:

```
function isNull<T>(x: T): null extends T ? boolean: void {
   return (x === null) as any;
}

// Error
declare const a: string;
if (isNull(a)) { }

// OK
declare const b: string | null;
if (isNull(b)) { }
```